# What is the correct way to check and delete temp table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, temporary-tables, drop-table

Approach 1:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyTempTbl') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #MyTempTbl;
```

Approach 2:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [tempdb].[sys].[objects]
    WHERE [name] = N'#MyTempTbl')
    DROP TABLE [#MyTempTbl];
```

What is the correct way to check and delete temp table?

The context is a stored procedure invoked by an agent job.

I have tried  querying the [tempdb].[sys].[objects] and notice that the global temp table gets the same name, where as a local temp table gets name with underscores at the end like this MyTempTbl______. So I was wondering whether there is a standard way to check if temp table exists and if so to drop it, I am looking for syntax that would work for both local and global temp tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Approach 1 has the advantage of actually working correctly.

Approach 2 doesn't work for local temporary tables because the entry in `[tempdb].[sys].[objects]` has the internal system-generated name. It does work for global temporary tables.

You could also use [`DROP IF EXISTS`](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/drop-if-exists-new-thing-in-sql-server-2016/ba-p/384562), but in stored procedures (and other modules), it's [unnecessary](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/tempdb-files-and-trace-flags-and-updates-oh-my/ba-p/385937). In stored procedures, temporary tables are automatically dropped at the end of the procedure.

> ...an explicit drop of a temp table in a stored procedure is unnecessary and thus not recommended...

Note it does not matter (from a [caching perspective](https://www.sql.kiwi/2012/08/temporary-object-caching-explained.html)) whether you explicitly drop a temporary table at the end of a procedure or not. Either way, the temporary table can still be cached.

It's generally not a good idea to use a generic name like `#MyTemp` for local temporary tables in modules. Use something specific to the module to prevent the problems described in [Can A Temp Table Name Cause Plan Cache Bloat?](https://sqlity.net/en/2853/temp-table-cache-bloat/)

Comment: This link: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/tempdb-files-and-trace-flags-and-updates-oh-my/ba-p/385937 - it says *The above practices help ensure that the temp tables you create within your stored procedures are eligible for caching. *

Comment: @variable Is that where you stopped reading? Or did you notice the three struck-out words in the next sentence (" or explicitly dropped") and the EDIT that follows? That was an error in the original version that Pam was kind enough to correct after I pointed out the mistake.

Comment: Right I had stopped reading, thanks for pointing this. So is it harmless to do the if exists drop check at the beginning of the stored proc? I am looking at a sql server that has got this check on almost every store proc (probably the developer used it during development of the SP code in SSMS). So will it be better to remove these checks from the start of the SP? Or is this harmless?

Comment: @variable I would remove them, yes. They're pretty pointless.

Comment: Are the implications to consider for stored procedures that create and drop global temp tables?

Comment: @BillRoberts No